# Tool that can sort NCBI taxonomy ids based on phylogeny

Tags: phylogeny, phylogenetics, taxonomy

I have a set of NCBI txids (of varying ranks) that I want to sort in some way (e.g. a table or a tree, the way it is sorted isn't super important), based on the current NCBI data for phylogenetic relatedness.

I don't have so many txids that I can map phylogenetic relationships at a really high resolution, but if, say, the txids for `plants, mammals, chordates, humans` could be sorted so that humans are nested within mammals which is nested within chordates, which is separated from plants.

Is there a tool that can do this?

Comment: not sure that i understand. what do you mean by "sort"? if you just want a tree of your taxids, what is wrong with tools like this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/guide/howto/gen-com-tree/